# BreakPoint are not working in ipad?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I have seen many question like this before but in my case it is not working only on iPad.
I have breakpoints that are not working in iPad but when I Run my application on Simulator or on the iPhone all the breaking point are working properly.
I have tried install SDK again, Delete the previous build, clean , clean all target & Load Symbols Lazily.

Comment: Are you compiling in Release or Debug mode?

Comment: I am in Debug mode that why it is working on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the iPad, restart, clean the project, run normaly, stop, activate breakpoints, and re-try.

Comment: @nik:In what kind of methods are your breakpoint ? I mean, what kind of system / user action should call them ?

Comment: I am trying this on Viewdidload method , on Tap and and even in appdelegate file no where it is working.....

Comment: @nik's:did you think about restarting your mac and unpluging your cable ?

Comment: @nik's : Did you try to send the iPad through the window ?

Comment: ya i have tried almost every thing but don't know why it is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4877/discussion-between-niks-and-oliver)

Comment: @nik's : sorry, but I have to leave for a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when Xcode is started and device is already connected to MAC, the device appears in XCode even if the device iOS version is higher than the XCode iOS version. At this time the break point doesn't work.